# Atlassian Stash fork doesn't render readme in overview tab

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I have:

1. a central repository with default branch being master
2. it's Atlassian-Stash fork, where default branch is cfr
3. a local repository where I added a README.md file.

Upon pushing to fork, I can see README on *Files* tab - it's listed among files in repo and it's rendered well under the list, as expected.

However *Overview* tab still displays:

> There are no readme files in
>   MyUser / ForkName, cfr.

Is there something I missed or should I file a bug report?

EDIT:
There is a limitation in Atlassian on readme size, but my readme fits it.
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/STASH-3197

Per Charleso (Stash dev) advise, I've opened an issue with Pirate Ninja Unicorn, author(s?) of Overview plugin. https://bitbucket.org/pirateninjaunicorn/stash-readme-parser/issue/16/readme-seen-in-files-tab-reported-as - shall see what they'll reply.

Comment: the overview and the files tabs both point to same branch? Does the `README.md` get added on master branch? It looks like stash is looking for readme file on cfr branch. Correct me if I got something wrong.

Comment: Both tabs SHOULD look at same branch: 1) it's default branch for whole fork 2) the box right under tab chooser states same branch for both tabs. As for master: it has a different file (lowercase) and it AIN'T displayed either (on Overview tab, even when I switch to master branch) . It shouldn't matter if readme is NOT on master if both tabs display a different branch anyway.

Comment: Stash developer here. The overview tab is provided by a third-party plugin. You might want to see if it's a known bug, or raise one, here: https://bitbucket.org/pirateninjaunicorn/stash-readme-parser

Comment: Thank you @charleso - that was the right place to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in bug-fix for a previous issue apparently. Quoting Theresa Henze (from PNU):

> I can't seem to reproduce the problem. [...]
>   However, I fixed #15 and maybe this is no longer an issue. [...]
>   I just released version 1.2.1. Could you please check whether your problem still 
>   occurs in the updated version?

https://bitbucket.org/pirateninjaunicorn/stash-readme-parser/issue/16/readme-seen-in-files-tab-reported-as

Tested with newly released plugin version 1.2.1 and it works. Closed the issue, thanks to **Charleso** for pointing me in the right direction!